# How to open VDB files under Ubuntu ?

Tags: 13.04, mono, database, sql

I'm working with a software that uses VDB ([VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/)) to archive log files, while everyone else uses windows and can use the Vistadb software, I'm unable to do so using my Ubuntu OS, does anyone knows how can those file be viewed under Linux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following I found while looking at this ...

- VistaDB is an Embedded SQL Database Engine for .Net and mono.
- It uses Blowfish encryption to encrypt the database content.
- Anyone with a license that has the database can open it and use their own program to connect but I only saw Windows software that can do this.

The only mentioning of Linux in regards to vistaDB is [this reply](http://community.gibraltarsoftware.com/Forums/yaf_postsm20976_MonoTouch-and-Mono-for-Android.aspx#post20976), though the full reply is more about android:

> VistaDB may work under Mono, but we do not have the resources to test and validate it for Mono, so such use is considered "experimental". In theory, it can work in Mono--such as under Linux on a PC.
>
> When we took over VistaDB we had to focus our efforts on the core product for standard machines and operating systems (ie. various versions of Windows).

When we have alternatives like MySQL, SQLite and Firebird not a lot of Linux users will be tempted to buy a license and install Windows to use it. So you are probably on your own here (not saying it is not possible in Linux with mono but you would need to do a lot of experimenting yourself).

Comment: I was afraid of this answer :/, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: yeah well I always hate it when the answer is something like this :D good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the database was built for VistaDB 4.x (*.vdb4), you're out of luck.  However, 3.x (*.vdb3) works fine under WINE.  Can't confirm with 2.x (*.vdb) since I can't find that version.